# Edit pojo in for firebase database

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying to modify the POJO below to create a new data structure in my DB.

```
public class Registration implements Parcelable {

    private String color;
    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private String reg_date;
    private String license_plate;
    private String id_type;
    private String id_number;
    private String picture;
    private int service_type;
    private int fuel_type;
    private int vehicle_type;
}
```

All looks fine, but when the function on the server calls the onWrite for DB. If I print the obj it looks like:

```
{ fuelType: 0,
  idNumber: '0000000',
  idType: 'L',
  licensePlate: 'III000',
  serviceType: 0,
  vehicleType: 0 }
```

The code below does the trick.

```
exports.runt = functions.database.ref('/vehicles/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {

    if(!event.data.val() || event.data.previous.val()){
        console.log("Not Adding a new vehicle");
        return;
    }

    var uuid = event.auth.variable ? event.auth.variable.uid : null;

    console.log(event.data.val());

    retrieveVehicleInfo(event, uuid);

    retrieveTickets(event, uuid);

});
```

Is there a way to clean or refresh an object in firebase, because I don't understand why my object keeps looking like the old one.

Comment: Firebase interprets your POJO as a JavaBean class, and camel-cases the property names. faruk's answer show the annotations needed.

Answer (score 1):

In your pojo put `@PropertyName(YOUR FIELD)` in your variable, getter and setter

For example :

```
@PropertyName("reg_date")
private String reg_date;

@PropertyName("reg_date")
public String getRegDate() {
    return reg_date;
}

@PropertyName("reg_date")
public void setRegDate(String reg_date) {
    this.reg_date = reg_date;
}
```

Comment: I don't think in this case you need the annotation on the field itself.